# Can Raiden Network transfers occur offline?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, sidechain, offline, raiden

Since Raiden is off-chain, could I theoretically set up some channels among a group of local parties and conduct transactions offline via NFC, bluetooth, wifidirect, etc.?

Since it's off chain and only needs to sync to the blockchain when closing channels is this possible?

Thanks, I'm very new to Raiden and struggling through the documentation to find answers to the questions I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this question when you reposted it to Reddit, but I'll post it here as well:

Yes, you definitely can. The issue though is that if one of the parties does go online, they can begin to exit Raiden with an earlier signed state. So if you sent me 1 ETH on June 4th, and I send you 2 ETH on June 5th, I could go online and submit the signed state from June 4th where I have more ETH. If you don't go online, you can't make a claim that there is actually a newer state. This is why you generally have to go online once in a while with any kind of state channel